# Why did my oxygen run out in FTL?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I was attacked in an ion storm (sensor and 50% power) and my O<sub>2</sub> was damaged. I repaired it and killed the intruders but my O<sub>2</sub> kept running down and everyone died. There were no fires.

Why would that happen?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A couple things could have caused this:

- Did you leave your doors open leading to the outside?
- Did you have a breach in your starship?
- Was your O<sub>2</sub> powered?

Further update what probably happened was you entered an ion storm which made you use 50% of your power, at this time your oxygen was unpowered and led to your death when it was never given power again.

Comment: O2 being unpowered is a likely culprit. Wouldn't a breach only affect its room unless the doors were open?

Comment: That was probably it since the doors were closed. Was so far in and killed by something so stupid.

Comment: @wtjones: That would be this game's motto, yes.

Comment: @wtjones this game thrives on YASD, not as much as nethack but comes up enough

Comment: @Halfwarr YASD ALSO stands for YOUR A STUPID D----- ironically.

Comment: @Ender And here I was thinking it meant "You Are So Doomed"

Comment: I'll just leave this here http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Yet_Another_Stupid_Death ;)

Answer (score 13):

When you run across the "nebula storm" event, your reactor power is reduced by 50%, and the ship will depower quite a lot of your systems as a result.  It's highly likely that your Oxygen system had it's power removed for the duration of the fight.  Having the system damaged means that even if it was powered previously, that power went back into the reactor pool and you likely powered up something else with it.

Additionally, when you jump out, the ship sometimes doesn't repower all your systems, even though your reactor power is restored.  It helps to double check everything one jump after a nebula storm to ensure that all of your systems have come back online properly.

Comment: I've never seen O2 be depowered by the nebula itself. I'm pretty sure the game has a sort of priority power list that it works off of. The most likely scenario is when it was damaged it depowered as usual and the surplus power unit went into something else either accidentally or intentionally-and-forgot so he suffocated himself.

Comment: @Shaderach I've had the game unpower my O2 before

Comment: @Ender - yeah, I've had it happen as well in the 6 weeks since I posted that.